# NullPointer Exception on checking size of List

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I get a null pointer exception for this statement.

**accountList.getTrxnList().getTrxns().size() > 0**

accountList is a list of accounts I get from an external API call. And I am sure that a non-null accountList value is returned.But I am not confident about getTrxns() has any values. So before processing I check whether there are any Trxns but this also results in a null pointer exception.

This is my model class

```
public class AccountList{

    private TrxnList trxnList;

    public static class TrxnList {

        private List<Trxn> trxns;

        public List<Trxn> getTrxns() {
            return trxns;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please point out why this is raising nullpointer exception? I did some research on this so I cannot understand this raising nullpointer exception even if there are no items in trxns List.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your List is not instantiated, only declared. You need to put:

```
private List<Trxn> trxns = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Must be `new ArrayList<>()`

Comment: That's if you want to create an ArrayList, but then you'd declare the variable of type ArrayList too, right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ssr1369.

accountList= jaxbConfig.unmarshal(result, AccountList.class); Actually I unmarshal to get my object. Other variables are not instantiated as well and they do not give an error.That is my problem.

Comment: As a good practice, you should always make sure everything's instantiated properly. So, as a general rule, if you don't use a constructor, I'd add to the getter "if(trxnList==null) trxnList=new List<>();" before returning it.

Comment: @Ssr1369 Off-Topic, but yes you can instantiate a list as ```private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();```. Actually you must, because ```private List<String> list = new List<>();``` causes a compiler error ```Cannot instantiate the type List```.

Answer (score 2):

You could also catch the `NullPointerException`, but I do agree with the other commenter that the exception is resolved by instantiating the List.

```java
public class AccountList{

    private TrxnList trxnList;

    public static class TrxnList {

        private List<Trxn> trxns;

        public List<Trxn> getTrxns() {
            try
            {
                return trxns;
            }
            catch(NullPointerException e)
            {
                // handle the list==null case here
                // maybe instantiate it here if it's not:
                trxns = new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class AccountList{

    private TrxnList trxnList;

    public static class TrxnList {

        private List<Trxn> trxns;

        public List<Trxn> getTrxns() {
            return Optional.ofNullable(trxns).orElse(new ArrayList())
        }
    }
}
```